# Can the reflection of a massive (quantum) particle from a mirror be considered a Lorentz boost

Tags: terminology, lorentz-symmetry

Can the non-collinear reflection of a massive (quantum) particle from a mirror be considered a Lorentz boost??

Answer (score 2):

No. A Lorentz boost is not a physical event. It is a change of coordinates.

A Lorentz boost is when you change from one coordinate system to another which is moving at constant velocity relative to the first.

In your situation, if you analyzed the collision from a frame where the mirror was stationary, then analyzed it again from a frame where the particle was stationary, you might perform a Lorentz boost to move from one scenario to the other. This is not necessary though; you can analyze the collision in any reference frame you want, and the physical event does not have a Lorentz boost associated with it because boosting is our free choice, done for our own analytical purposes, and is not tied to physical events.

Comment: thanks for the great comment and correcting my thinking....

Comment: thanks for the excellent explanation and correcting my faulty thinking.  However, please clarify why we would need to use Lorentz Boost at all. When you say: " if you analyzed the collision from a frame where the mirror was stationary, then analyzed it again from a frame where the particle was stationary, you might perform a Lorentz boost to move from one scenario to the other", Does this mean I would want to use a Lorentz boost to find out what the moving particle is "experiencing" in its stationary frame??

Comment: Yes, if you already analyzed the situation in a frame where the particle is moving, applying the appropriate Lorentz boost would tell you about what happens in a frame where the particle is stationary.

Comment: OK; thanks again...so what happens to spin.. ex., I have a massive spin 1 particle (in my frame) hits a mirror and 40* angle and bounces off. If I am not mistaken, quantum spin changes to -1 (in my frame) since it is relative to its momentum, correct?  What happens to the spin in the particles frame ,,how do I determine the spin change ?